# chroot jail + ssh key refused

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ansible, ssh-keys, chroot

I'm trying to create a `chroot` jail on an EC2 Instance (Amazon AMI Linux). I've tried the instructions here: https://allanfeid.com/content/creating-chroot-jail-ssh-access

My EC2 instance has an SSH key called `demosystems.pem` and I can successfully login (as expected) via `ec2-user`.

```
$ groupadd sshusers
$ adduser -g sshusers janedoe
$ mkdir -p /var/jail/{dev,etc,lib,lib64,usr,bin}
$ mkdir -p /var/jail/usr/bin
$ chown root.root /var/jail
$ mknod -m 666 /var/jail/dev/null c 1 3
$ cd /var/jail/etc
$ cp /etc/ld.so.cache .
$ cp /etc/ld.so.conf .
$ cp /etc/nsswitch.conf .
$ cp /etc/hosts .
$ cd /var/jail/usr/bin
$ cp /usr/bin/ls .
$ cp /usr/bin/bash .
$ cd /sbin
$ wget -O l2chroot http://www.cyberciti.biz/files/lighttpd/l2chroot.txt
$ chmod +x l2chroot
$ l2chroot ls
$ l2chroot bash
$ nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Match group sshusers
          ChrootDirectory /var/jail/
          X11Forwarding no
          AllowTcpForwarding no
```

I've also tried using the `geerlingguy.ansible-role-ssh-chroot-jail` Ansible role:

```
---
- name: Create chroot jail
  hosts: chroot
  become: yes

  vars:
  - ssh_chroot_jail_users:
      name: janedoe
      homedir: /home/janedoe
      shell: /bin/bash

  roles:
    - geerlingguy.ssh-chroot-jail
```

In **both** cases, the error I get when trying to SSH in as `janedoe` is:

`No supported authentication methods available (server sent: public key). Server refused our key.`

Therefore, I believe the problem to be somewhere in the final step. Setting the `Match group` above.

Any thoughts / ideas?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

`.ssh` directory and `authorized_keys` file doesn't exist. Solution with Ansible is to create two post tasks:

```
post_tasks:
  - name: Create SSH Directory
    file:
      path: /home/janedoe/.ssh
      state: directory

  - name: Copy SSH from ec2-user to janedoe
    copy:
      remote_src: yes
      src: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
      dest: /home/janedoe/.ssh/authorized_keys
      owner: janedoe
```